# HTML5 Video Cannot be Played

Tags: html, video

I'm using `video` tag to play a video on my browser (Chrome). I can play my mp4 videos with this tag only if the file is below (around) 135MB. If the files larger than 135MB, the video cannot be played (same format & same extension). Anyone know what happened and how to solve that?

My code to open the file:

```
<?php
   $filename=$_GET['filename']; //parameter identifying the file to be downloaded. Should not be direct path as in this simple example, rather than the id of the file's data stored in a database. You need to add that piece of code.
   header('Content-Type: text/plain'); //set MIME type - you need to store this along your path to the file, you can get it from $_FILES['uploadedfilename']['type'] when a file is uploaded via php
   header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename"); //advises the browser to open the file outside of the browser, not within a plugin
   readfile($filename); //outputs the file
?>
```

My code to read the file:

```
<video controls width="320">
     <source src="video_view.php?filename='.$query['v_drive'].'://upload/'.$query['c_group'].'/'.$query['c_name'].'/'.$query['v_link'].'" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video_view.php?filename='.$query['v_drive'].'://upload/'.$query['c_group'].'/'.$query['c_name'].'/'.$query['v_link'].'" type="video/webm">
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" width="720" height="576" style="position:relative;">
        <param name="movie" value="assets/flashfox.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;src=video_view.php?filename='.$query['v_drive'].'://upload/'.$query['c_group'].'/'.$query['c_name'].'/'.$query['v_link'].'"" />
        <embed src="assets/flashfox.swf" width="320" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;src=video_view.php?filename='.$query['v_drive'].'://upload/'.$query['c_group'].'/'.$query['c_name'].'/'.$query['v_link'].'"    allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />          
    </object>
     Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>
```

Comment: was qt-faststart (or equivalent) run on the file? or is the moov at the back?

Comment: Nope. There's no qt-faststart. I'm using a file to open the movie. Already update my code above.

Comment: Not 'faststarting' the file may be your problem then. If you can post the file, I can tell you for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this link from google: http://licson.net/post/stream-videos-php/ which can be used to play any video from php file and it works very great.